# Mac menu bar not showing some icons?

Tags: mac, macos, macbook-pro, menu-bar

I'm running Yosemite 10.10.1 on a MacBook Air (early 2014), and I'm not seeing some icons on menu bar and folder and on browsers too. I have been trying to look for what's wrong on System Preferences, but I can't seem to find the answers! I attached the images to make it more clear. [image: screen shot for my osx 10.10.1]

Comment: Does it happen in another account?

Comment: did not check let me check with the guest account!!

Comment: @ganbustein i did login as a guest and the icons were there, as matter of fact even when i'm logging i do see the icons but as soon as i'm on the account there are gone.

Comment: It might be worth doing a Safe Boot. It looks like maybe some icon cache is messed up. Safe Boot causes some caches to be re-built. Admittedly, I see nothing about icon caches in the documentation for Safe Boot (or anywhere else for that matter), but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: so how do i launch safe mode, I'm also running but campo,with windows 7.

Comment: @ganbustein thanks a lot irun safe mode and after restart the icons showed up. thanks foor the tip.

Comment: @ganbustein  got twitter!!?

Comment: @drexx did you figure out a solution for this? I had the same issue but restarting my mac fixed it. Don't know what caused it.

Comment: @Kostub Deshmukh booting in safe mode and restart the computer did work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To boot up in safe mode you can hold down the shift key when restarting.

I would go to the Finder and open any window and right click or control click in the gray part of title bar. See what your settings are set to.

[image: screen shot of icon and text option]

There is also a new update to the system 10.10.2 that was just released. Maybe this will fix it, along with a bunch of other problems we have all been having with Yosemite. (I hope! :).

As far as the menu icons, I know that some of the system settings as in airplay there is a button that says "Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available" and there are more I am sure.

Good luck my friend.